# Hibernate : org.hibernate.QueryException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have an org.hibernate.QueryException and I have trouble understanding why.

The property langue_id not resolved by hibernate is defined in my entity Conditionnement.

**StackTrace**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: langue_id of: fr.sita.g2fm.domain.referentiel.Conditionnement
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1805) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.getType(EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1760) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UNIQUE_CONDITIONNEMENT_DESIGNATION", columnNames = {
        "designation"}))
public class Conditionnement implements IdObject, Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7096113289274101792L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private Long codeConditionnement;

  @NotNull(message = ERROR_CODE_MANDATORY_FIELD)
  private String designation;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "langue_id")
  @NotNull(message = ERROR_CODE_MANDATORY_FIELD)
  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CONDITIONNEMENT_LANGUE")
  private Langue langue;
}
```

**Finally the method in my DAO**

```
  @Override
  public List<Conditionnement> find(ConditionnementCriteria conditionnementCriteria) {
    Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(Conditionnement.class, "c");
    criteria.createCriteria("c.langue_id", "l", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

    return criteria.list();
  }
```

Do you have any idea what's causing this exception ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `c.langue_id` doesn't exists as it stands. Try with `c.langue`. Hibernate goes for actual property names and not the underlying column name in the database when you create a query/criteria

Comment: Do you have the DB schema for Langue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception is straightforward when it says:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: langue_id of: fr.sita.g2fm.domain.referentiel.Conditionnement

So the problem is that `Hibernate` can't find the property `langue_id` in your `Conditionnement` entity, and that's because `Hibernate` is an [**Object/Relational Mapping (ORM)** framework](http://hibernate.org/orm/) so it treats `objects/entities` and not `tables`, so it will look for the class `properties` and not the table `columns`.

And in your entity you have:

```
private Langue langue;
```

So you need to have this query:

```
@Override
public List<Conditionnement> find(ConditionnementCriteria conditionnementCriteria) {
    Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(Conditionnement.class, "c");
    criteria.createCriteria("c.langue", "l", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `c.langue_id` to `c.langue` like below as hibernate is not able to find the column with name `langue_id`.

```
public List<Conditionnement> find(ConditionnementCriteria conditionnementCriteria) {
    Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(Conditionnement.class, "c");
    criteria.createCriteria("c.langue", "l", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

    return criteria.list();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is hibernate do not find mapping present for column `c.langue_id` in `Conditionnement` though there column present in the table. You should change `c.langue_id` to `c.langue`

```
public List<Conditionnement> find(ConditionnementCriteria conditionnementCriteria) {
    Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(Conditionnement.class, "c");
    criteria.createCriteria("c.langue", "l", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

    return criteria.list();
  }
```